# Cant find the solution to fix this error - vb.NET, mvc, web

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I get an error when I try to build my project.
`'SSLAccessFiltercannot' be used as an attribute because it does not inherit from 'System.Attribute'`

Anyone here familiar with this error or see the problem here?
Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:
Added some code as example

```
<AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Get), SSLAccessFilter(AccessType.NotAllowed)> Function GroupDiscussionView(ByVal elementId As String, ByVal topicId As Integer) As ActionResult
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you have an attribute: `<SSLAccessFilter()>`.
It seems, by looking at the error, that SSLAccessFilter does not inherit from [System.Attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute.aspx) and you are using it as an attribute. This can't be done.

Not much else can be said without some more information. Like code.

If SSLAccessFilter is your own class you need to inherit it from System.Attribute:

```
Public Class SSLAccessFilter
       Inherits System.Attribute
  ...
End Class
```

Comment: Added line of code where the error occurs, its one of many places but its basicly the same error as in `does not inherit from 'system.attribute'`.

Comment: The error message you are getting is your answer. An Attribute must inherit from System.Attribute.

Comment: Found the solution, it was a very silly mistake. I forgot to add `Imports System.Web.Mvc` to certain classes. Thanks for thinking with me :)